# How to pass multiple data sets in XML in MbUnit

Tags: unit-testing, mbunit, gallio

Suppose I have a code module which accepts a variable number of *DataRows*:

```
Public sub Process(Dt As DataTable)
End Sub
```

I want to pass one or more test *DataRows* to my MbUnit test module:

**Test 1**:

```
DataRow 1: Green, 23
DataRow 2: Green, 24
```

**Test 2**:

```
DataRow 1: Green, 23
DataRow 2: Green, 24
DataRow 3: Blue, 44
DataRow 4: Red, 55
```

How would I setup an XML data file with these tests in MbUnit?

Question 2:

Suppose I want to pass meta data about the test data? For example "Color Name" or "Distance". How would I add this meta data to the XML file?

Thanks,

Ed

Answer (score 0):

There is some documentation in the **[Gallio Wiki](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=start)** which explains [how to use an XML data source](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3adata-driven_testing%3axmldata) for your test parameters and how to bind them with metadata. But unfortunately, the built-in XML data source attribute is not that much flexible.

I guess that the best solution is to create your [own data factory](http://gallio.org/wiki/doku.php?id=mbunit%3adata-driven_testing%3afactory). Something like this maybe:

```
[TestFixture]
public class MyFixture
{
  [Test, Factory("GetSampleDataTables")]
  public void MyTest(DataTable dataTable)
  {
     var foo = new Foo();
     foo.Process(dataTable);
     // Make assertions...
  }

  public static IEnumerable<object> GetSampleDataTables()
  {
    foreach (...) // Read your XML data file...
    {
      var sampleDataTable = new DataTable();
      // Populate your sample data table from XML...
      yield return sampleDataTable;
    }
  }
}
```